# Running plain JS in react?

Tags: reactjs, p5.js

I have `p5.js` files with sketches, and I want to load them on the page.

I don't want to rewrite all the sketches to things like `p5.createCanvas` instead of just using `createCanvas`.

I created a file called mySketch.js which contains a function which exports all my `p5.js` code.

But then I get the error: `error 'createCanvas' is not defined.`

I installed `p5js` via npm, and imported P5 from it:

```
import P5 from "../components/p5";
```

but the error still there, also I did not add something like `P5.createCanvas()`, because that's what I want to avoid.

I also added the `p5js` script to the head, and I can see its there on the head on dev tools.

But the error still remains.

Any ideas on how to load `p5js` sketches in react?

Comment: What part of file you want to load. See [export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export)

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that you may have executable code inside plain js made by you. In this case you need to reimport npm module **p5js** inside your custom file **p5** on the top line.

is your error appearing only when you try to import your custom module?

note: do not forget to execute your **createCanvas** in **componentDidMount**(and destroy it in **componentWillUnmount**) or if you use modern react - in

```
useEffect(() => {
  /// build sketches 
  return () => {
    /// destroy sketches.
  }
}, [])
```

or place your code in jsfiddle or codepen to check it

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to create new instance of p5 in mounted component?

```
  componentDidMount () {
    this.canvas = new p5(this.props.design, this.sketchRef.current)
  }
```

This example refers to situation when you want to use p5 "wrapper" which accepts function with p5 design. Here you have full example:

```
// Sketch.js

import React, { Component } from 'react'
import p5 from 'p5'

class Sketch extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.sketchRef = React.createRef();
    this.canvas = null
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    this.canvas = new p5(this.props.design, this.sketchRef.current)
  }

  componentDidUpdate () {
    this.canvas.remove();
    this.canvas = new p5(this.props.design, this.sketchRef.current)
  }

  componentWillUnmount () {
    this.canvas.remove();
  }

  render () {
    return <div className="sketch" ref={this.sketchRef} />
  }
}

export default Sketch
```

Now we are able to pass function with p5 design.

```
// App.js
<Sketch design={Shape}></Sketch>
```

p5 shape with your design

```
export function Shape (p) {
  const canvasSize = 710;
  p.setup = () => {
    p.createCanvas(canvasSize, canvasSize);
    p.background('#fff');
    ... // your p5 code
  }
}
```